# I want to show how many item there is in cart using MVC viewbag in layout

Tags: layout, model-view-controller, cart, viewbag

I want to show how many item there is in shopping cart using viewbag in layout. Can you please help. When I add breakpoints, viewbag bear the value but it doesnt come up in browser.

my controller;

```
 public ActionResult CartDetail()
    {
        Cart s = Session["cartpastahemen"] as Cart;
        int ItemNumberInCart = 0;
        foreach (var item in s)
        {
            ItemNumberInCart++;
        }
        ViewBag.ItemNumberInCart = ItemNumberInCart;
        return PartialView("_Cart", Session["cartpastahemen"] as Cart);
    }
```

my layout view;

```
<li><a href="/Home/Cart" style="font-size:larger"> Sepetim @(ViewBag.ItemNumberInCart)</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem using Partial View.